# Problem with SQL Server 2000 Cursor Not Fetching NEXT

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I've got a SQL Server 2000 db. I need to run the following cursor to fire a trigger on individual records (the trigger will only operate on one record at a time).

```
DECLARE @REC as bigint

DECLARE coil1_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Rec# FROM coil1 WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '2011-05-10 06:00:00' AND '2011-05-10 07:00:00'

OPEN coil1_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM coil1_cursor INTO @REC

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
    Print @Rec
    UPDATE coil1 SET ShiftLength=Null WHERE Rec#=@REC

    FETCH NEXT FROM coil1_cursor INTO @REC
END
CLOSE coil1_cursor
DEALLOCATE coil1_cursor
```

If I comment out the UPDATE line, I get sequential numbers from Rec# field as expected. If I uncomment the UPDATE line, the batch goes into an infinite loop. When I stop the batch, it only shows updating the first record it gets to. It's like the FETCH NEXT gets stuck. Any ideas why?

Comment: A trigger that only operates on one record at a time needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Can you fix the trigger so it will operate on all records "FROM inserted"? If so, simply use UPDATE coil1 SET ShiftLength = Null WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2011-05-10 06:00:00' AND '2011-05-10 07:00:00'. I think you're trying to implement the wrong solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: I once removed a cursor in a trigger and an insert of only 40,000 records went from taking over 45 minutes to less than a minute. It is a very poor practice to use cursors in a trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM: In this case, I don't think the cursor is in the trigger. I think he's using a cursor because the trigger was incorrectly written to process only a single row.

Comment: @joe, that's just as bad! First fix the trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM: That was the point of my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the default cursor options (including dynamic). Try using a much more efficient cursor for your purposes:

```
DECLARE coil1_cursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR ...
```

But for the real fix, Joe is absolutely right - this shouldn't be a cursor at all. You can accomplish the same thing with a single update statement. No cursor, no infinite loops, no waiting:

```
UPDATE coil1 
   SET ShiftLength = NULL
   WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN '2011-05-10 06:00:00' AND '2011-05-10 07:00:00'
```

(As an aside, `[Timestamp]` is a horrible column name because it represents a data type that has nothing to do with date or time. `Rec#` is not fabulous either. YMMV.)

Comment: I agree with all your comments, but as is often the case, we have to work with the cards dealt to us. The LOCAL STATIC... options fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm just seeing now that the cursor isn't inside the trigger, sorry for misinterpreting. Well, why doesn't the external code clean up the junk that the trigger isn't doing correctly? Can you go into details about what the trigger is doing to one row only that it should be doing to all the rows?

Answer (score 3):

Because you're updating the table referenced by your cursor, you should declare your cursor as STATIC.

```
DECLARE coil1_cursor CURSOR STATIC FOR
SELECT Rec# FROM coil1 WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '2011-05-10 06:00:00' AND '2011-05-10 07:00:00'
```

Comment: As a side note, `INSENSITIVE` is a synonym for `STATIC`

Comment: @Filip But it's so much more work to type! And also more prone to typos. :-)

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for the answer for couple of hours. I thought that updating the referenced table won't matter since we are declaring cursor only once. Declaring cursor as static was the way ;)